# Regex pattern using korn shell [Version AJM 93u+] for comma separated values

Tags: regex, shell, ksh

I'm trying to create a regex pattern in korn shell. I'm new to this korn shell scripting and its regex.

The regex is needed for the following case:

The `allowed values` are as below:

```
80,01,00
80,00
01
00,80,01,02
```

The `not allowed values` are as below:

```
 80,   --> with comma in the end.
,01,   --> comma at the start and end.
,00    --> comma at the start.
 8     --> with only one digit
800    --> with three digits
```

I have tried the below **regex pattern:**

```
^(*([0-9][0-9][,])+([0-9][0-9])*([,][0-9][0-9]))$
```

and the snippet from script is as below:

```
if [[ $END_POINT_LIST =~ ^(*([0-9][0-9][,])+([0-9][0-9])*([,][0-9][0-9]))$ ]]; then
            echo "Input validation passed!"
            export RETURN_CODE=16
            exit 16
        else
            echo "[FATAL] The parameter doesn't match the expected pattern."
            export RETURN_CODE=16
            exit 16
        fi
        ;;
```

Above regex pattern is not working as expected.

I'm not able to get the mistake in the regex.

Any suggestions to point out the mistake will be of great help.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

In addition to the accepted answer from @degant, I would like to mention the following.

The mistake in the regex being posted in the question is,
The characters `* and +` are placed in the start of pattern-list.

If that is changed to place the `* and +` after the pattern-list it works fine.

**The below corrected regex works fine as well:**

```
^(([0-9][0-9][,])*([0-9][0-9])+([,][0-9][0-9])*)$
```

Comment: Do you also want a check to ensure that between each comma exactly 2 digits should be present?

Comment: yes. only two digits have to be allowed.

Comment: Updated the answer with a check for two digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex to match numbers separated by commas and ensure commas aren't present in the front or the end:

```
^\d{2}(,\d{2})*$
```

In case the shell doesn't support `\d` and `{2}`:

```
^[0-9][0-9](,[0-9][0-9])*$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFHRut/2)

**EDIT:** Suggestions as per @Doqnach

Comment: Replace the `\d` with `[0-9]` in case the regex engine in korn shell does not support `\d`

Comment: @degant thank you! the edited answer to limit for two digits not working in korn shell..not sure why. I will check the syntax for ksh

Comment: @Vignesh Changed `[0-9]{2}` to `[0-9][0-9]` and updated the answer. Hope this works!

Comment: @degant it works perfect for the cases posted in the question! thank you!